# Angular 2+ "click outside" of 2 components, not just 1

Tags: angular, event-handling

I have a multi-component sidebar toggle, app/button/sidebar are all in their own components, button/sidebar are children of app (or at least loaded within the app component, assume this is a child)

Still not quite up to speed on the cross-component communication aspect of  Angular, I'm utilizing a service in this case.

What I'm after: if neither component *button* or *sidebar* are clicked (anything outside these two components)... collapse sidebar.

At current, I'm toggling a boolean state on a "visible" variable in a service to expand/collapse the nav.

I've tried all manner of methods with little success. What are some ways to accomplish this? Or at least somewhere I can read to get close and take it from there?

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-component-communication

Comment: Take a look at how Material's sidenav approached this: https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/sidenav

Basically, you'd want to create an absolutely-positioned overlay over the page and render the sidenav element inside of that. You can set the click event on the overlay itself to be the 'blur' for the sidenav. `@angular/cdk` has an Overlay that's useful for this.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code works if the `document:click` event handler toggles the `visible` flag:

```
@HostListener("document:click", ["$event"])
onClick(event) {
  this.visible = this._ref.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
}
```

To prevent the button click from reaching the document level, stop the event propagation:

```
<toggle-sidebar (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></toggle-sidebar>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-component-communication-rdkzeb) for a demo.

Comment: Actually this was what I was already trying to achieve, just wasn't sure how to call the e.stopPropagination() properly within Angular, a little different from javascript. But this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a directive to listen to outside panel click:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    @Output() clickOutside: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter<Event>();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
    onDocumentClick(event: Event) {
        if (!this.isClickInElement(event)) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }

    private isClickInElement(event: Event): boolean {
        return this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
    }
}
```

Now where you have the menu attach this directive and bind to it's output and call the method to collapse sidebar or do your action. Ex:

```
<ol (clickOutside)="collapseSideBar()">
```

Comment: I've tried this, and works similar to how I have it setup at current, the "button" that toggles is outside the component, so won't actually toggle.

Comment: may be add it to higher level which contains the sidebar.. and emit events from it to the child for hiding?

Comment: You can handle `clickOutSide` in both sidebar and button. And if both are clicked outside, close your sidebar. You can achive the same by @Output/EventEmitter in both of your child components and listen to them in your `app.component.ts` file.

Comment: @robert as it was long, I have added it as answer below.

Comment: just a note to please use the `Renderer2` as opposed to direct DOM manipulation in Angular

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `clickOutSide` in both sidebar and button. And if both are clicked outside, close your sidebar. You can achieve the same by @Output/EventEmitter in both of your child components and listen to them in your `app.component.ts` file.

So, to summarize:

1. Check `clickOutSide` in sidebar, and emit the same to parent, i.e. `app.component.ts`
2. Check `clickOutSide` in toggle button, and emit the same to parent, i.e. `app.component.ts`
3. In `app.component.ts`, handle above emits and perform checks :

   - When toggle button is clicked outside, sidenav is clicked outside and sidenav is open, we should close the sidenav.
   - When toggle button is clicked inside, functionally, sidenav will be clicked outside. But, we have to change sidenav to be clicked inside. So, we will manually change that flag. Otherwise, if you click in sidenav but outside toggle button, sidenav will be closed.

I have edited your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-component-communication-5gahrf), considering the above scenarios.

Comment: Interesting, there's so many ways to handle events across components. Hard to land on one.

Comment: Quick question: this seems more direct and compartmentalized, although it is slightly more code to accommodate, that said: Why in particular is this a better approach than the current selected answer? To be transparent, I'm a css/html/js dev, not a ts/angular dev. Just trying to grasp it. I can see this being something can be expanded upon easier, but not certain I grasp the full scope of this approach.

Comment: Part 1 - @darcher I am not sure if this is better than the accepted answer. It's just another approach. Personally, I prefer this, because, click event stays inside the component only, it's not leaked outside, we are handling what we want to share outside of the component. Let's say, in the accepted answer, going forward, to handle click, you will create a function `toggleClicked(ev:Event){ //your logic to be performed before ev.stopPropagation(), and then ev.stopPropagation() is called //  }` and in your template `<toggle-sidebar (click)="toggleClicked($event)"></toggle-sidebar>`.

Comment: Part 2 (This is in connection with Part 1) - so, in your function `toggleClicked` you are passing whole **click** event. To see how many properties it has, see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Properties or https://imgur.com/qLh6gWo. As you would see, it has lot of data, which we are passing from HTML to Component. That's the reason, I would avoid solution which has whole **click** event object in it. Even, Angular's official docs recommends not to use it, checkout here : https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That is a great explanation and read. I'll certainly take a look at it and compare. That helps a lot.